# Generate dates PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code and wondering if there is a simpler way without all the ifelse conditions

```
if ($year == 13){
    $shyear = '2012 / 2013';
}elseif ($year == 12){
    $shyear = '2011 / 2012';
}elseif ($year == 11){
    $shyear = '2010 / 2011';
}elseif ($year == 10){
    $shyear = '2009 / 2010';
}elseif ($year == 9){
    $shyear = '2008 / 2009';
}elseif ($year == 8){
    $shyear = '2007 / 2008';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I love [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). Clean, simple, fast, readable.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', $year);
$shyear = $dt->format('Y')-1 . " / " . $dt->format('Y');
```

This will result in `$shyear` to be this:

```
2007 / 2008
```

Let's test it:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '8');
echo $dt->format('Y')-1 . " / " . $dt->format('Y');

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '9');
echo $dt->format('Y')-1 . " / " . $dt->format('Y');

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '10');
echo $dt->format('Y')-1 . " / " . $dt->format('Y');

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '11');
echo $dt->format('Y')-1 . " / " . $dt->format('Y');

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '12');
echo $dt->format('Y')-1 . " / " . $dt->format('Y');

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '13');
echo $dt->format('Y')-1 . " / " . $dt->format('Y');
```

Results:

```
2007 / 2008
2008 / 2009
2009 / 2010
2010 / 2011
2011 / 2012
2012 / 2013
```

Works with year 2000 as well!

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '0');
echo $dt->format('Y')-1 . " / " . $dt->format('Y');
```

Results in `1999 / 2000`.

Comment: nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

$shyear = strlen($year) > 1 ? sprintf('20%d / 20%d', $year-1, $year) : sprintf('200%d / 200%d', $year-1, $year);

```
<?php
$year = 15;
$shyear = strlen($year) > 1 ? sprintf('20%d / 20%d', $year-1, $year) : sprintf('200%d / 200%d', $year-1, $year);
echo $shyear;
?>
```

Wrote this little piece of code and it outputs "2014 / 2015"

Comment: yeah, fixed it now.. This works for the years 2000 to 2099

Answer (score 0):

Another way, considering that you only need a particular range of years, would be to use associative arrays

```
$array = array( "7"=>"2007", 
                "8"=>"2008", 
                "9"=>"2008",
                "10"=>"2010",
                "11"=>"2011",
                "12"=>"2012",
                "13"=>"2013");

if ($year >= 8 and $year <= 13) {
      $shyear = $array["".($year-1).""]."/".$array["$year"];
}
```